# Convert an iterable object to tuple in python C api

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api

I have an iterable `PyObject` that I need to pass as the list of arguments to a Python callable, ala

```
xs = [1,2,5,7]
some_function(*xs)
```

However, `PyObject_CallObject` only allows tuples to be passed as the arguments' container.

I'm not sure, though, what is the best way to create a new tuple containing the elements of an iterable. Here's a tentative code:

```
PyObject* unpack_call(PyObject* callable, PyObject* args) {
  PyObject* tuple;
  if (PyTuple_Check(args)) {
    tuple = args;
  } else {
    PyObject* iter = PyObject_GetIter(args);
    if (!iter) return NULL;

    tuple = PyTuple_New(0);

    for (Py_ssize_t pos=0; ; ++pos) {
      PyObject* arg = PyIter_Next(iter);
      if (!arg) break;

      PyTuple_SetItem(tuple,pos,arg);
    }
  }
  return PyObject_CallObject(callable,tuple);
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to grow the size of the tuple myself or not. What's confusing me is the sentence in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c._PyTuple_Resize) saying:

> The tuple will always grow or shrink at the end.

I'm also not sure if I need to increment or decrement reference counts for any of these objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're much better using [`PySequence_Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Tuple) which can create a tuple directly from an iterable. There's probably other similar options to do this too.

If you did want to do it your way then you do need to call `PyTuple_Resize` each time you add to it (or resize it in chunks possibly). What the sentence

> The tuple will always grow or shrink at the end.

tells you is that extra space is at the end of the tuple.

`PyTuple_SetItem` steals a reference, so you don't need to touch the reference count of the items you're adding. You should be doing some error checking though - `PyIter_Next` can raise an exception. You also need to decref `iter` and the tuple when you're done with them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! For some reason, I thought that sentence was using "end" in the temporal sense, as in "at the end of an operation".